# Grab Program's Console Output

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, console

I am creating a network administration program for a company I'm currently doing some contract work with (irrelevant I suppose)

As part of the program, I would like to have a console/telnet(type) clone. I have a working directory system, where I can essentially read all files in directories, and change directories. I also have an easy FTP protocol set up. However I would like to arbitrarily speak to different programs with the standard input/output procedures programmatically. I'm not opposed to DLL injection techniques, and other methods, as this is a benign program. If possible it would be awesome if I could just directly use the console easily. (system() would possibly work, however this doesn't allow continued communication or reading back of output)

I'm thinking so far of grabbing the PATH environment vars and utilizing that for std commands (ipconfig, netstat, etc) My networking library makes communication easy, but I'm just not sure how to interface with the program's console...

**TL;DR:**

Are there any predefined ways of standard console communication between programs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Jerry mentioned, what you're looking for is a pipe ([CreatePipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Two of them actually - one for input and one for output. You then create the new process with them set as stdin/stdout/stderr in [STARTUPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passed to [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can then use [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [ReadFile](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx&ei=kfAXTtTnIoPViALjn_3RBQ&usg=AFQjCNHWrLHw_3-PoR208RsDdMx8Nh-Z7w), [PeekNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365779%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and friends to communicate.

A complete example is available on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

And make sure you don't fall into these common pitfalls (which luckily Raymond Chen just happened to document recently):

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/07/10183884.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/06/10183368.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/08/10184375.aspx

PS, this is sooooo much easier in Python with the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.

Comment: Thank you! I have seen pipes before, but as of yet, I've done nothing with them. This looks sufficient. Thank you (again)!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is usually to spawn the child program with [`_popen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx). This will give you a handle to write to the child's standard input, or read from the child's standard output.

If you need to do both, things get a lot uglier in a hurry. You usually have to create the anonymous pipes yourself and specify them in a call to [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx), which is, frankly, a pain.

Comment: That's just about exactly the information I needed, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Alright I've learned a TON about this in the last little while. And here's some information that some people may find useful =]

**Code To Create Process With Pipes/File Descriptors as Stdin/out/err:**

```
    STARTUPINFO startInfo;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;

    memset((void*) &startInfo, 0, sizeof (startInfo));
    memset((void*) &procInfo,  0, sizeof (procInfo));

    startInfo.cb = sizeof (startInfo);
    startInfo.dwFlags = (STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW);

    startInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE; //No Console Window, Thanks.

    startInfo.hStdInput   = (HANDLE)inHandle;
    startInfo.hStdOutput  = (HANDLE)outHandle;
    startInfo.hStdError   = (HANDLE)errHandle;

    char* pe = "cmd\0"; 
    //This is the program to execute (eg: c:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe)

    CreateProcess(NULL,pe,NULL,NULL,TRUE,0,NULL,NULL,&startInfo,&procInfo);

    return procInfo.hProcess;
```

Now this is all fine and dandy, but there's an additional little tidbit of information that has really helped me out here. You can use file descriptors for your handles (in/out/err) so you can use straight sockets, with no modification, and you will have direct access to the input and output of the process.

So my current method of creating a hidden console, is to connect two sockets together locally, then use one of the sockets as the stdInput && stdOutput && stdError descriptors for a child program that calls cmd. It's quick, and easy.

If you don't know how to connect some sockets together, just look into [beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Comment: You shouldn't use `+` for appending flags. Always use `|`. Some flags overlap and then you may get unexpected results.