# Controlling piped StdIn and StdOut

Tags: c, winapi, pipe

I've read some tutorials on the net on how to redirect stdin and stdout of a program, but I need some help on how to control it.

So far I have this:

```
HANDLE hSTD_OUT_READ;
HANDLE hSTD_OUT_WRITE;
HANDLE hSTD_IN_READ;
HANDLE hSTD_IN_WRITE;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
saAttr.nLength = sizeof(saAttr); 
saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
CreatePipe(&hSTD_OUT_READ,&hSTD_OUT_WRITE,&saAttr,0);
SetHandleInformation(hSTD_OUT_READ, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
CreatePipe(&hSTD_IN_READ,&hSTD_IN_WRITE,&saAttr,0);
SetHandleInformation(hSTD_IN_WRITE, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
memset(&cmdProcess,0,sizeof(cmdProcess));
memset(&cmdInfo,0,sizeof(cmdInfo));
cmdProcess.cb = sizeof(cmdProcess);
cmdProcess.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
cmdProcess.hStdError = hSTD_OUT_WRITE;
cmdProcess.hStdOutput = hSTD_OUT_WRITE;
cmdProcess.hStdInput = hSTD_IN_READ;
CreateProcess(NULL,"cmd.exe",NULL,NULL,TRUE,0,NULL,NULL,&cmdProcess,&cmdInfo);
DWORD BytesWritten;
WriteFile(hSTD_IN_WRITE,&cmd,sizeof(cmd),&BytesWritten,NULL);
CloseHandle(hSTD_OUT_WRITE);
DWORD BytesRecvd;
while(true)
{
    bSUCCESS =  ReadFile(hSTD_OUT_READ,&recvd,sizeof(recvd),&BytesRecvd,NULL);
    printf(recvd);
    if( ! bSUCCESS || BytesRecvd == 0 ) break; 


}
```

At this point, I have received the windows cmd printout message but that wasn't the expected respone to my stdin which was "whoami". What do i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to write to your `stdin` pipe. But you have to create one first with [CreatePipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You also need a different pipe for `stdin` and `stdout` or else the `cmd.exe` will just go into an endless loop of erroring on its own output.

There is a complete example on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx

An old SO question that may also help:

[Grab Program's Console Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633056/grab-programs-console-output/6633117)

Comment: Ok, so far I have created two handles and char array:
I am doing everything right so far? 
CreatePipe(&hReadPipe,&hWritePipe,NULL,0);
WriteFile(hWritePipe,&cmd,sizeof(cmd),NULL,NULL);

Comment: Where's the code? I suggest you start off the MSDN example and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

You passed `NULL` as the final two parameters to `ReadFile`, which is not permitted. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says

> This parameter [lpNumberOfBytesRead] can be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL.

Comment: Thanks for catching that one ;)

Answer (score 0):

You keep changing your question, so the answers make no sense except for the last one. You are getting the command prompt startup message because that is the first thing that cmd prints to stdout. Everything is working as expected.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm gonna have to close this one, and re-open a new one.