# Load the output of another command line program into mine

Tags: c++, command-line, input

Ok suppose I have a program ( in windows a .exe file ) and when I run it, it outputs some information... now I'm writing another program ( in c++ ) and I need it to automatically run that .exe file and read the output so that it can process that information for further actions...

what should I do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grab Program's Console Output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633056/grab-programs-console-output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `popen` or on windows (per comment) `_popen`.  Basically it functions as the thing behind the `|` in `some program | thing`.

Normally I'm against posting complete code but I literally wrote this today and have it on hand, so, here you go.  From what I understand C++ doesn't have a *great* interface that replaces `popen` but if you're bringing in the boost libraries or something at that layer there are solutions.

Note I use `char[10]` because in my application I know the output will be that short.

```
   PopenWrapper(const std::string& command) {

            fd = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
            if(fd == NULL) {
                    throw PopenException("Failed to open command: " + command);
            }
    }

    std::string get() {
            char line[10];
            fgets(line, sizeof(line), fd);
            return std::string(line);
    }

    ~PopenWrapper() {
            if(fd != NULL) {
                    pclose(fd);
            }
    }
```

Comment: On Windows, Microsoft has sadly decided to use the non-standard name [`_popen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead of `popen`.