# Replacing _popen with CreateProcess

Tags: c++, createprocess

I have a function that uses `_popen` like this:

```
fp = _popen("dir C:\", "r");
```

and then it does something for each output line like this

```
while (fgets( line, sizeof line, fp))
```

I need to have the same functionality by using `CreateProcess` but I don't know how. Any ideas with the "dir C:\" example (along with reading each line of the output)?

Comment: Why not try something first? "don't know how" is very broad and suggests that it's not the problem that you "don't know" something, but rather that you didn't even try to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Because I'm new to C/C++ and I don't have much expirience to do so. Instead of blaming me for asking a question and "editing" my exclamation marks, you could use your expirience to actually help me EVEN with a link. Don't you think? Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: I'm not "blaming you" for anything. I'm trying to encourage you to use some basic googling skills, and experiment with some code. You don't need much experience to try things. That's the best way to learn, instead of just asking someone to write the code for you.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to write ANY code for me, i need directions. Links, references, samples, anything that isn't >150 lines of code (like microsoft's examples). That's all.

Comment: Consider reading the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) then. This site is about particular problems concerning particular code samples. Questions asking to create examples or provide links are off-topic.

Comment: I see... particular code samples :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633056/grab-programs-console-output

Comment: You seem to think that showing an example of a bad question that is not closed and has upvotes contradicts what I've said. You're wrong.