# How to capture console output to log file on MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc

I have program in which child process was created inorder to capture output from external.exe. Program is able to capture output from external.exe but all I wanted is after capturing the output it should write on my log which is my MFC application. (Microsoft Visual Studio C++).

```
const wchar_t* a;
TCHAR cmd[] = _T(...........);
if (!CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) 
    a=(LPWSTR)CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si,&pi);
this->AddLog2(_T("Query"),a);
```

***Error : 
Error   8   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'BOOL' to 'const wchar_t *'***

Thank you very much. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Pipes are for more than smoking.

Comment: Ok, any idea how to capture that output to some variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grab Program's Console Output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633056/grab-programs-console-output)

Comment: Hard to understand how you got from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) to `a=(LPWSTR)CreateProcess(...);`...

Comment: No, Creating process and getting output of console that job is done. I need to channelize my output to log file now. In the link you gave they are interested in creation of sockets which I don't need. @Captian Obvlious

Comment: My idea was  taking output from CreateProcess (which is already coming on console ouput in my program) and assign to a variable "a" which I have declared as const wchar_t *a . So, I typecasted  CreateProcess to (LPWSTR). and was trying to pass to AddLog2 function. 
@IInspectable

Comment: I posted a link to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx). It **clearly** describes the return value as an error/success indicator. If you don't understand what a return value is, then at least the next sentence should have had you thinking: *"Note that the function returns before the process has finished initialization."* And now you'd need to send future console output back in time.

Comment: OK got it. It returns zero or non-zero value depending on error/success.
" now you'd need to send future console output back in time" , I didn't get this line. Can you please explain how to capture the console output ?